# rewriting search suggest in jQuery

Tags: jquery, search, keyboard-events

First, I know that there are jQuery plugins for search suggest.  The reason I'm asking this is because I wrote one for my specific needs and I am interested in learning how to make the script in jQuery (rather than just using a plugin).  See code that I pasted to pastebin -- I hope that's ok.

Original: http://pastebin.com/VFuXY4iX

Somewhat jQuerified: http://pastebin.com/S86ES8bH

The two things that I am struggling with are as follows:

-- The original (and the jQuery one currently) accesses child nodes by their DOM child index (see `unhilite()` function).  I haven't found a way to do this in jQuery.  The closest thing that I can find is `.next("selector")`, but the elements don't have a selector that I can key on except for the DOM index.  I was thinking of overcoming this by doing something like:

```
$('.hilited')
    .next('li')
        .addClass('hilited')
    .end()
    .removeClass('hilited');
```

Would this work well?  Edit: even if it does work well, is there a way to access DOM indexes like that (for future reference)?

-- Second, I don't know specifically how to bind keyboard events with jQuery (without using a plugin, which I want to avoid - again for learning purposes).  I think `bind()` or `keydown()` might work, though.

```
$('#target').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == '40') {
        //next
    } else if (event.keyCode == '40') {
        //previous
    }
)};
```

Anybody have any suggestions?  Thanks SO, you're my favorite!

PS- sajax_do_call is Mediawiki AJAX syntax for anyone that isn't familiar...

Comment: Hi Guys, this is the slowest question I've seen.  Should I delete it because it's not worth answering or do people not know and I should keep it - not sure of proper etiquette?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered some of my own question.  I could use jQuery's [nth child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector if I wanted to.  The other suggested solutions do work, but i'd still be open to suggestions.